# Google Analytics - How to show all primary dimensions in the table

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, Ecommerce reports like Performance report, is there a way to show all the primary dimensions as a column in side the table ?
[GA report image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTnUJ.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only enter a secondary dimension in reports. Instead, you can create a **Custom Reports** in *Customization* menu (on the left bar) where you can generate a report with multiple dimensions and metrics.